# Enum's working with .setText in android/java

Tags: java, android, enums, stub, settext

I am building a Android app in Java, use a Enum variable in a .setText scenario for a XML TextView, i fully understand my Enum is in the wrong data type, but i need your help to work out a alternative to this.

The code where i'm using the setText:

```
package com.mastermind;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


  public class Guess_database extends Activity {

public ArrayList<Guess> guess_list;
public static int guess_counter = 0;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.guess_layout);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    for (Guess g : guess_list) {

        View stub = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guess_stub, null);
        ((TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.guess)).setText(g.v1 + ", "+ g.v2);
        ((TextView)stub.findViewById(R.id.guess_positions)).setText(g.c1);

    }

}
   }
```

And here is the class for my Enum variable:

```
  package com.mastermind;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Guess implements Serializable
{
static int v1, v2, v3, v4;

public static GuessStatus c1,c2, c3, c4;

enum GuessStatus
{
    CORRECT,
    WRONG,
    CORRECT_WRONG_PLACE;
}
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i don't understand what you do with the views once they are inflated? Also, guess_list is null, and i don't understand what are v1-4 and c1-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
((TextView)stub.findViewById(R.id.guess_positions)).setText(g.c1.toString());
```

Comment: Thank-you! i thought that i had tried using toString, but i must of used it wrong?